# Friending class while there's an object of friending class inside friended class

Tags: c++, class, friend

the title might seem a little bit confusing but I'll try to explain that.
I've got a class `CGameMode`:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include "../Hero/Hero.h"
#include "../Weapon/Weapon.h"
#include "../Armor/Armor.h"

class CGameMode
{
private:
    CHero Hero;
    CWeapon Weapon;
    CArmor Armor;

    std::string FileName = "save.txt";
protected:

public:
    void InitializeGame();
    void CreateGame();
    void LoadGame();
    void SaveGame();
    CGameMode* GetGameMode() { return this; }
};
```

As you can see, the class contains objects of classes: `CHero`, `CWeapon` and `CArmor`. Let's take a look on one of these classes:

```
#pragma once

#include "../Enemy/Enemy.h"
#include "../GameMode/GameMode.h"

class CHero : public CEnemy
{
private:
    int Energy = 0;
    int ExperiencePoints = 0;
    int Level = 0;

    friend class CGameMode;
protected:

public:
    CHero();
    CHero(std::string Name, int Health, int Energy, int ExperiencePoints, int Level);
};
```

The most important is this line of code:

```
friend class CGameMode;
```

(`CArmor` and `CWeapon` also friend the `CGameMode` class).

The problem is the program does not compile. But if I remove *Hero*, *Weapon* and *Armor* members from `CGameMode` class, the program compiles and everything works just fine.

So the question is: How can I make the `CGameMode` class friended with `CWeapon`, `CArmor` and `CHero` and in the same time, the objects of these classes can be contained by `CGameMode`?

Comment: "*The problem is the program does not compile.*" What is the full compiler error you receive?

Comment: Do you really need to be friends with everything? Friends should be used sparingly, if other classes need access to private members then the members should either be public or have accessor methods

Comment: As to your problem I suspect it is due to circular includes rather than friends (difficult to tell without a [mre] and the error message), see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes

Comment: After adding the missing bits the code you've given compiles without error: https://godbolt.org/z/aK9svT

Comment: You're approaching this from the wrong end. Design your class interfaces so friendship is unnecessary.

Comment: I never use `frind` keyword and IMO nobody should. Friendships creates code entanglement so it should be avoided.